# Chat messages does not update properly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the full code for the chatViewController. Every time when I click send button, the text messages will have some duplicate and fly out of text box as shown in this picture.

[image: Look at this picture]

However, when I exit the chat and re-enters,those message that fly out of the box are gone. It is not because of duplicated messages in Array, I believe it should be due to either Cache issue or the updating mechanism is wrong.
Every time when I close chat and re-enter, the fly out of text box chat does not exist, everything is fine. If I do not click on send Message,the Messages all reload fine.

It is only when I click send message, there will be a few (not all) messages that duplicate and fly out of box. When I exit the chat, and re-enter,the out of box chat will be gone and everything is normal.

I consulted with other programmers who saw my code and said it is most likely because when you click send button, it fetches complete dataset, and when it display on your screen, the old data on your screen (even though you have removed them from your array) messed up with the new data. I asked them how to solve it, they are not sure because they are Android developers.

A train of thought I was thinking: cache the old messages, add the new messages but make sure they do not conflict with the old messages in the cache?

```
import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseStorage
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import FirebaseFirestore
    import CoreData

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageText: UITextField!

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        back()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func sendTextMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    chats.removeAll()
    self.sendDataToDatabase(message: messageText.text!)
    messageText.text = nil
    self.loadPosts()
    self.loadPostsReceivedMessage()
        delayCompletionHandler {
          self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    let cellIdentifier = "chatNow"
    var chats = [Chat]()
    var posts = [Post]()
    var receiverIDNumber = ""
    var profileImageUrl = ""
    var senderString = ""
    var conversationsCounterInt = 0
    var timestamp = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourNibName = UINib(nibName: "ChatCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(yourNibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        print(receiverIDNumber)
        usernameLabel.text! = receiverIDNumber
        setUpProfile()
        set()
       print("is there anything"+profileImageUrl)
        //Making circular profile picture
        profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
        profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
        print("waka"+senderString)
        self.loadPosts()
        self.loadPostsReceivedMessage()
        delayCompletionHandler {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.title = "Chat"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func back() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
        let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab")
        present(tabViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }


    func set() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.senderString = dic["username"] as! String
                print("this"+self.senderString)
            }
        })
    }


   func sendDataToDatabase(message: String){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let timeStampString = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    db.collection("chats").addDocument(data: ["message": messageText.text!, "senderID": senderIDNumber!,"receiverID": receiverIDNumber,"timestamp": timeStampString,"profileUrl": profileImageUrl, "sender": self.senderString])
    { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
    }


    func logout(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login")
        present(loginViewController, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }


    func delayCompletionHandler(completion:@escaping (() -> ())) {
        let delayInSeconds = 0.3
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {
            completion()
        }
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return chats.count
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCollectionViewCell    
         let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    //Setup the messageReceived and messageSent
            if chats[indexPath.row].senderID == senderIDNumber {
            if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message{
                let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
                let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
                let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
                cell.messageSend.frame = CGRect(x:8,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
                cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
             //showOutgoingMessage(text: chats[indexPath.row].message)
                cell.messageSend.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
        }
            }
        else {
                cell.messageReceived.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
                let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message
                let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
                let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
                let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText!).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
                cell.messageReceived.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
                cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 4, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message {
        let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        }

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }



    //Get Message sent
    func loadPosts() {
        let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let chatsRef = db.collection ("chats").order (by: "timestamp", descending: false)
       let sentListener = chatsRef.whereField ("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!)
        .whereField ("receiverID", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
        .addSnapshotListener() {
            querySnapshot,
            error in
            guard let documentChanges = querySnapshot?.documentChanges else {
                print ("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for documentChange in documentChanges {
                if (documentChange.type == .added) {
                    let data = documentChange.document.data ()
                    print("Message send: \(data)")
                    let messageText = data["message"] as? String
                    let senderIDNumber = data["senderID"] as? String
                    let receiverIDNumber = data["receiverID"] as? String
                    let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? String
                    guard let sender = data["sender"] as? String else {return}
                   // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                    guard let profileUrl = data["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                    let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
    self.chats.append(chat)
    print(self.chats)
            }
                }
                   }
    }


    //Get message received
    func loadPostsReceivedMessage() {
                let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
                print("thecurrentreceiver"+senderString)
                print("thecurrentsender"+receiverIDNumber)
            let receivedListener = chatsRef.whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: senderString).whereField("sender", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
            .addSnapshotListener() {
                querySnapshot,
                error in
                guard let documentChanges = querySnapshot?.documentChanges else {
                    print ("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                for documentChange in documentChanges {
                    if (documentChange.type == .added) {
                        let data = documentChange.document.data ()
                        print("Message received: \(data)")
                        let messageText = data["message"] as? String
                        let senderIDNumber = data["senderID"] as? String
                        let receiverIDNumber = data["receiverID"] as? String
                        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? String
                        guard let sender = data["sender"] as? String else {return}
                        // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                        guard let profileUrl = data["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                        let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
                        self.chats.append(chat)
                        print(self.chats)
                        self.chats.sort{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
                        }
                }
    }
    }



    func setUpProfile() {
        guard let url = URL(string:  profileImageUrl) else { return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, reponse, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                })

            }

        }
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. What does *fly out of text box* mean? The image included in the question isn't really showing anything other than a chat - it looks ok to me so what's the issue? Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Taking note of the *minimal* part as there's entirely too much unrelated code in the question. Can you clarify what the actual problem is? It sounds like any sent messages do not repopulate when closing and then reopening the chat. Is that correct?

Comment: This question is duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/q/51179292/9731167 You shouldn't be asking the same thing several times. Instead continue in the same thread